# Pass allowDiskUse:true in Node-RED

Tags: mongodb, node-red

I am trying to pass aggregated query in Node-RED but I am getting following error:

> MongoError: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in.

I tried paasing allowDiskUse: true in different possible ways like:

`msg.payload.options = { allowDiskUse: true };`

`msg.payload.allowDiskUse = true;`

`msg.options = {allowDiskUse: true};`

but none of them is working!

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb node does not support passing options.

I'm sure the [project](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes) would accept a pull request to add the capability

Comment: No, it doesn't look like it